# REST URL mapping with parameter in web.xml

Tags: url, rest, servlets, web.xml

What `url-pattern` should we be putting in web.xml for making my servlet listen on this path, `/{name}/servlet`?

Here, `name` is a variable so I should be able to listen on 
`http:8080//testproject/xyz/servlet`

or

`http:8080//testproject/abc/servlet`.

Here `xyz` is a variable name.  This is basically a REST URL with parameters, though i can use `@Path` and `@PathParam`, but I want to do it in web.xml only.

```
<servlet-name> A </servlet-name>
<url-pattern> /{}/sevlet </url-pattern>
```

Any clues to what put for variable string in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into servlet filters

Comment: but using Servlet filters I have to code for filtering every possible request. which is quite messy

Comment: ya dats true. but then u have to move to REST to avoid d trouble.